# Ecto + Elixir: How do I update a hash map field?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a User model with a `matches` field that is of `:map` type. I'm trying to update it in the console, but it's not working:

```
iex(16)> changeset = User.changeset(u, %{ matches: %{ "123": true } })
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, errors: [], data: #VideoChat.User<>,
 valid?: true>
iex(18)> VideoChat.Repo.update(changeset)
{:ok,
 %VideoChat.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
  device_identifier: "123", id: 1,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-06 23:02:56>, matches: %{},
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-06 23:02:56>}}
iex(19)> u = User |> VideoChat.Repo.one
[debug] QUERY OK source="users" db=1.2ms
SELECT u0."id", u0."device_identifier", u0."matches", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at" FROM "users" AS u0 []
%VideoChat.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
 device_identifier: "123", id: 1,
 inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-06 23:02:56>, matches: %{},
 updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-06 23:02:56>}
```

This is my user model:

```
defmodule VideoChat.User do
  use VideoChat.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :device_identifier, :string
    field :matches, :map

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:device_identifier])
    |> validate_required([:device_identifier])
  end
end
```

How do I update a :map field?

Comment: Are you able to add in your user model file please?

Comment: @HarrisonLucas updated!

Comment: Try including `:matches` in the call to `cast`. Change `cast(params, [:device_identifier])` to `cast(params, [:device_identifier, :matches])`.

Comment: it worked!!!! thanks! I have another question, do you know how I would write a query for the `matches` field? i want to check for `all users where matches['cool'] != nil"`

Comment: No idea about that. Probably a good question.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help with the query!